# How to get the max of two values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, max

I tried but failed:

```
mysql> select max(1,0);
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '0)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 652, accepted):

Use [**GREATEST()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

E.g.:

```
SELECT GREATEST(2,1);
```

Note: Whenever if any single value contains null at that time this function always returns null (Thanks to user @sanghavi7)

Comment: example: select greatest(queue.count - 1, 0) from queue;

Comment: one thing need to keep in mind that whenever if any single value contains null at that time this function always returns null as answer!

Comment: There is also [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Comment: how can i run a sub query as a parameter to `GREATEST` so that i can get values for a cirtain column

Comment: To prevent the problem with null you can use ifnull. E.g. `select greatest(date1, ifnull(date2, "0000-00-00 00.00:00")) from table1 where date2 is null;` will get you date1.

Comment: sadly, if you are using `LEAST`, and you put something like `SELECT LEAST(20000, COUNT(*)) FROM massive_table WHERE index_breaking_filter;` it can't shortcut the logic after the `COUNT(*)` exceeds 20k - it takes just as long as the query without the least.

Comment: If some values may be null, you can do `GREATEST(COALESCE(column1, 0), COALESCE(column2, 0))`

Answer (score 33):

To get the maximum value of a column across a set of rows:

```
SELECT MAX(column1) FROM table; -- expect one result
```

To get the maximum value of a set of columns, literals, or variables for each row:

```
SELECT GREATEST(column1, 1, 0, @val) FROM table; -- expect many results
```

Comment: Watch out for null values with `GREATEST`. Any null value will cause the function to return null. To prevent this, you can do `GREATEST(COALESCE(column1, 0), COALESCE(column2, 0))`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function with not nullable fields.
If one of this values (or both) can be NULL, don't use it (result can be NULL).

```
select 
    if(
        fieldA is NULL, 
        if(fieldB is NULL, NULL, fieldB), /* second NULL is default value */
        if(fieldB is NULL, field A, GREATEST(fieldA, fieldB))
    ) as maxValue
```

You can change NULL to your preferred default value (if both values is NULL).

Comment: This is why I honestly hate MySQL. What a tremendous amount of work to do such a simple thing.

Comment: This can be simply replaced with `select COALESCE(GREATEST(fieldA, fieldB),fieldA,fieldB) as maxValue`. It is overcomplicated

Comment: If some values can be null, you can do `GREATEST(COALESCE(column1, 0), COALESCE(column2, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT GREATEST(value1, value2) AS maxvalues;