# Conditional values for calculated column in MySql

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two date columns, which works just fine as:

```
select (ship_date - due_date) AS DaysTaken;
```

Basically, I want to determine if orders were shipped on time and, if not, how many days late. This works fine, as expected, except, if the order is shipped early, I get a negative number.  What I'd like to do is to evaluate the results and return 0, if it calculates a negative value.

I don't know how to do this in a MySQL select statement.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Near duplicate of [How to get the max of two values in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565688/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to replace negative numbers with 0:

```
select GREATEST((ship_date - due_date),0) AS DaysTaken;
```

Comment: @Merrill: if an answer resolves your question, [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) it. If it's useful but doesn't resolve your question (or does resolve the question, but there's another answer that is better), upvote the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  GREATEST(ship_date - due_date, 0) AS DaysTaken
```