# How to get the minimum of 3 values where some of them may be null in MySQL using LEAST()?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found this question ( [How to get the max of two values in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565688/how-to-get-the-max-of-two-values-in-mysql) ) while looking for ways to compare discrete set of values.

I want to be able to get the **minimum** of few **selected** values where some of them may be `null` because they are optional but the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) says:

> If any argument is NULL, the result is NULL.

Comment: So why is your question how to do it using `Least` specifically?

Comment: Added LEAST in the title so that I don't confuse anyone this is MAX/MIN question. Any other working methodology is appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `COALESCE()` function on the nullable values:

```
select LEAST(COALESCE(@foo, <max int>), COALESCE(@bar, <max int>));
```

if you get the max int value, then both were null (unless there's a decent chance you could actually have the max int value as a real argument, then more logic is necessary)

Comment: @MarkByers - true... I can't wrap my brain around a case where I would use LEAST() on character data, though.

Comment: @Jeremy: to order words lexicographically - find the first one in a lexikon.

Comment: @ypercube that seems a textbook case for order by/ limit to me... using `LEAST()`... well, I suppose you could do it.  I can honestly say I've never used it, though, and have not felt its lack.

Comment: I don't know about the char "max" but I guess it depends on the data. This solution (with the max int) works even better if the discrete set has a known maximum which is way lower then the max int.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
LEAST(COALESCE(col1, col2, col3),
      COALESCE(col2, col3, col1),
      COALESCE(col3, col1, col2))
```

Obviously this doesn't scale well to more than 3 values.

Comment: it's an interesting approach, although I don't know how practical it is.  Why reference the other columns like that?

Comment: Oh I cannot argue that it will work, I just envision a case where you are running LEAST() against three of the exact same number because only one value wasn't null.  Seems like a waste to me, but it probably makes no difference one way or another.

Comment: It seems like a waste to me as well. The max number seems more light - Less comparisons to do.

Answer (score 1):

Works, is easily extendible, and doesn't rely on any values not being found in the data but probably heinously inefficient!

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
Id int primary key,
col1 int null,
col2 int null,
col3 int null
)
```

Query

```
SELECT id,
       Min(CASE c
             WHEN 1 THEN col1
             WHEN 2 THEN col2
             WHEN 3 THEN col3
           END)
FROM   x,
       (SELECT 1 AS c
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3) t
GROUP  BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hard code a big number say 99999.

LEAST(   IFNULL(COL_1,999999) ,
         IFNULL(COL_2,999999) ,
         IFNULL(COL_3,999999) ,
         IFNULL(COL_1,999999) )

i.e. just add IFNULL then the value or column name with a big enough integer.