# MySQL Select minimum/maximum among two (or more) given values

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to `SELECT` the minimum or maximum among two or more values. I'd need something like this:

```
SELECT MAX_VALUE(A.date0, B.date0) AS date0, MIN_VALUE(A.date1, B.date1) AS date1
FROM A, B
WHERE B.x = A.x
```

Can I achieve this by only using MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the max of two values in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565688/how-to-get-the-max-of-two-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` function to achieve it.

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(A.date0, B.date0) AS date0,
    LEAST(A.date1, B.date1) AS date1
FROM A, B
WHERE B.x = A.x
```

Both are described here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I'm shocked to have learned of LEAST and GREATEST only after 20 years in the business :-O

Comment: 10 years here !

Answer (score 32):

I suppose you are looking for:

[`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

and

[`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Answer (score 22):

Just watch out if NULL is likely to be in a field value ...

```
SELECT LEAST(NULL,NOW());
```

and

```
SELECT GREATEST(NULL,NOW());
```

both return null, which may not be what you want (especially in the case of GREATEST)

Comment: Which, for new comers, can be solved with IFNULL(<field>, <some-value>)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT GREATEST(A.date0, B.date0) AS `date0`,LEAST(A.date0, B.date0) AS `date1`
  FROM A 
  JOIN  B
    ON A.id = B.role;
```