# How can I calculate a minimum number of A and B on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, min

How can I calculate a minimum number of A and B on mysql?

Command 'min()' means something else on the SQL.

Comment: You probably want `LEAST()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Select minimum/maximum among two (or more) given values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445828/mysql-select-minimum-maximum-among-two-or-more-given-values)

Comment: Have you seen http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function to get a minimum number from two numbers:

```
LEAST()
```