# Fetching minimum value based on two column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which look like:

```
ID     Fig1     Fig2
A-1    10       -18
A-1    15        20
A-1    25        75
A-2    18        22
A-2    34        70
```

Now I want to fetch minimum value against each unique id by considering `Fig1` and `Fig2`.

Output Would be:

```
ID     Min Value
A-1   -18
A-2    18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `UNION` the columns and find the `MINIMUM` value.

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(D.Fig1) MinValue
FROM(
    SELECT ID,Fig1 FROM YourTable
    UNION
    SELECT ID,Fig2 FROM YourTable
)D
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    MIN(LEAST(Fig1, Fig2)) AS Min_value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Simple `CASE When` and `Min` Fucntion statment :

```
        Select ID,
        CASE WHEN min(Fig1)>min(FIG2) Then min(FIG2)
        WHEN min(Fig1)<min(FIG2) Then min(FIG1)
        Else NULL End AS FIG
        from 
        #TABLE 
        Group by ID
```

> **OutPut :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe duplicate of [MySQL Select minimum/maximum among two (or more) given values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445828/mysql-select-minimum-maximum-among-two-or-more-given-values)

I suppose you are looking for:

```
GREATEST()
```

and

```
LEAST()
```

here u'll find a working fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a762df/2

the resulting query would be

```
select ID, LEAST(MIN(Fig1),MIN(Fig2)) from dummy group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:

```
SELECT ID, LEAST(Fig1, Fig2) AS Min_value 
FROM testTable 
GROUP BY ID
```