# Earlier date between two date columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL version 8.0

Given a table:

```
id      date1      date2
1      2020-01-01  2020-01-02
2      2020-03-03  2020-05-02
3      2020-04-04  2020-02-11
```

I would like to create additional column that chooses min(date1, date2).

I know min(date1) = column-wise earliest date but how can I do row-wise minimum operation on dates?

Desired output should look like this:

```
id      date1      date2         min(date)
1      2020-01-01  2020-01-02    2020-01-01
2      2020-03-03  2020-05-02    2020-03-03
3      2020-04-04  2020-02-11    2020-02-01
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: answering your own question is fine, but don't put the answer at the bottom of the question, enter it as "Your Answer" below

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
[MySQL Select minimum/maximum among two (or more) given values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445828/mysql-select-minimum-maximum-among-two-or-more-given-values)

Simply use `least` function -> id, date1, date2, least(date1,date2)

I had to search for a while to find the answer so I am hoping this would lead to answer quicker.